# Detail about SQL query hints in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I am very new to SQL queries and developing a report using the SQL Server 2008. I was trying to find ways to optimize my query and came across something called as SQL Hints. I researched some sites and it said it overwrites the existing optimizing policy which SQL decides for the query.

I would like to know if the same will work for a view? Because I am using views to extract data.

Please guide.

Comment: Probably you won't outsmart Query Optimizer with Hints. Better think about indexing and materialization of views.

Answer (score 0):

Since view is a saved query, query hints also apply to the query behind view. My humble guess is that you don't have to use hints to optimize your query, look around indexes and ensure your query uses sargs for optimization.